# Confusion on adding noise using normal distribution in Python

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, probability-theory

I am very confused about how to sample measurement error using normal distribution (Gaussian pdf) in Python.

What I want to do is just to create noise (error) under Gaussian pdf and add it to measured values. In short, I put the problem as follows:

**Inputs:**

- M(i) - measurement value; i = 1...n, `n` - number of measurements;

**Output:**

- M_noisy(i) = M(i) + noise(i);

  where, `noise(i)` - noise in measurement; `M(i)` - measurement value.

**Important:** This noise should be as a zero-mean Gaussian noise with variance equal to, 10 % of the measurement value.

I put the following code but I could not continue...

**My code:**

`import numpy as np`

```
# sigma - standard deviation of M
# mu - mean value of M
# n - number of measurements

# I dont know if this is correct or not:
noise = sigma * np.random.randn(n) + mu;

## M_noisy(i) - ?
```

Thanks for any answers/suggestions in advance.

Comment: did you find any answers to your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
random_scale_ammounts = np.random.randn(n) 
#creates a list of values between -1 and 1
offset_from_mean = sigma *random_scales   #randomly -std to +std
noise =  offset_from_mean + mu;

clean_y_data = np.arange(n)
noisy_y_data = clean_y_data + noise
```

might be what you are after?

Comment: Thanks,but your answer is not clear. what do you mean by `random_scale`? and why to put `np.arange(100)` which is not equalt to `n`? Let's say my measured data is temperature in Celcius. Then, I want to add some noise (as we discussed) whose measurement unit should also be in Celcius. That means no "minus" data should be considered in noise term, right?! Is the 3rd line in your code exactly the same that I am talkin about?